# Can anyone identify this 2-pin connector (male & female)?

Tags: connector, identification

I'm trying to find the type of connector in order to build an extension cable, that's used to connect to a speaker.  The top clicks in and one of the pins has a angle to its housing to ensure correct connections.

I've looked on various electronics ordering sites, but haven't been able to find the name of the connector.

[image: connector attached][image: connector ends]

Comment: Quite sure it's minifit. Molex or wurth.

Comment: Can you add some dimensions to your question? Pin pitch, size of male connector.

Comment: I'm thinking it's the micro-fit: Molex  [43640-0201](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/0436400201_CRIMP_HOUSINGS.xml) & [43645-0200](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/0436450200_CRIMP_HOUSINGS.xml)

Comment: Your phrasing names it sound like you need any locking connector. Or are you needing this same one?

Comment: Require banana for scale.

Comment: @KH, a banana plug, jack, or actual banana?

Comment: @Cristobol Polychronopolis Yes.  Yes I do.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the pic it matches housing 43645-0200 and 0436400201 You just need to know the AWG of the wire as these are just housings and you will need the contacts.

[image]
[image]
[image]